# MongoDB repository find by where parameter in list of accepted values

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongorepository

In **Java** **Spring-boot**, I am trying to have a **MongoRepository** finder method able to find all the documents in a collection where the value of an attribute is within a collection of accepted values.

My example is the following one :

My bean:

```
@Document
public class A {
    // some attributes
    private MyEnum enumValue;
}
```

My repository:

```
public interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<A, String>{
```

My service:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    public List<A> generateList(List<MyEnum> acceptedValues){
        myRepository.findBy????();
    }
}
```

Which finder method can I call to get all the documents where the attribute A#myEnum is contained within the acceptedValues list?

Answer (score 0):

I found this working solution, even if it is not optimal:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    public Set<A> generateList(List<MyEnum> acceptedValues){
        Set<A> res = new HashSet<A>();
        for (MyEnum e : acceptedValues){
            res.addAll(myRepository.findByMyEnum(e));    
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```